# Inserting line breaks into PDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, carriage-return

I'm generating some PDF file on the fly using PHP. My problem is I need to insert line breaks in some part of the text that will be inserted in the PDF file. Something like:

```
$pdf->InsertText('Line one\n\nLine two');
```

So it prints:

> Line one
>
> Line two

I know `\n` doesn't work on PDF, but do you guys know any character or something that represents a line break on these files?

Comment: "some third party code" : it would have been easier for everybody if you said which lib exactly (luckily it looks like thomasrutter did recognize it)

Comment: InsertText() doesn't appear in the fpdf manual so I doubt that the third party code is fpdf. I think it might be best to remove the fpdf tag

Comment: Returning to this question almost 3 years later I'm embarrassed by how vague it is.  Sorry.  I'm pretty sure I was referring to fpdf, or a variant of it I found somewhere.  I abandoned my plan of writing to PDF anyway (or at least, I used it for a while, and it was good, then abandoned it).

Answer (score 50):

If you are using fpdf, in order to be able to use line breaks you will need to use a [multi-line text cell as described here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm).

If you use this, then line breaks in your text should be interpreted and converted correctly.

Just a quick example:

```
$pdf->Multicell(0,2,"This is a multi-line text string\nNew line\nNew line");
```

Here, 2 is the height of the multi-line text box.  I don't know what units that's measured in or if you can just set it to 0 and ignore it.  Perhaps try it with a large number if at first it doesn't work.

Comment: sir, its not interpreting the \n as newline , its just printing it on the pdf as \n

Comment: @sqlchild - You must use the double quotes as mentioned below using the \n as mentioned here. It does work. Just tried myself.

Comment: @thomasrutter, I'm using FPDF as well. Is there any way to read `\n` in `Cell()` function? I have problems with positioning adjacent `MultiCell()` when it prints on the 2nd page. I really need to read `\n` in `Cell()`. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can in Cell()

Answer (score 21):

Your code reads

```
$pdf->InsertText('Line one\n\nLine two');
```

I don't know about the PDF library you're using but normally if you want \n to be interpreted as a line break you must use double quotes in PHP, e.g.

```
$pdf->InsertText("Line one\n\nLine two");
```

Answer (score 16):

I changed `'\n'` for **chr(10)** and it worked:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(0,5,utf8_decode($variable1 . chr(10) . $variable2),1);
```

Comment: This is because PHP takes text in single quotes (') literally, while text contained in double quotes (") is 'interpreted', so that means '\n' is a 2 character string, with a slash and an n character, while "\n" is a 1 character string, containing a single new-line character. ;)

Answer (score 7):

You state that

> 2 is the height of the multi-line text box

No it's not.
2 is the distance between lines of text.

I don't think there is a real way for calculating the height of the actual resulting text box, unless you use `GetY()` and then subtract the original Y value used in your `SetXY()` statement for placing the Multicell in the first place.

Comment: Oh my gosh.  I could not work out why the damn thing wasnt working correctly - All I wanted to do was print new lines! Then suddenly I read this.  How annoying.  It could be more specific in the documentation.  For *w* it merely states `Height of cells.`  That plural there is crucial to understand what It meant.  I assumed it was just the height of the box that I wanted to print in.  D'oh!

Answer (score 7):

Another option is to use [`TCPDF::Ln()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a00969cf629d72b3d29ee435f15906820). It adds a line to the PDF with the option to set the height.

If the newlines are within your content already then [`MultiCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece) is probably the way to go, as others have mentioned, but I find I like using:

```
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Line 1', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(0, 0, 'Line 2', 0, 0, 'C');
```

It confuses me that [`Cell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a33b265e5eb3e4d1d4fedfe29f8166f31) and [`MultiCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece) take in different arguments so I tend to stick to using [`Cell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a33b265e5eb3e4d1d4fedfe29f8166f31) only. Also it reads like a newline character for the PDF the same as `\n` reads like a newline character in text or `<br>` in HTML.

Comment: `$pdf->cell(0, 0, 'Line 1', 0, 1, 'C')` works fine!

Answer (score 6):

I have simply replaced the "`\n`" with "`<br>`" tag. Worked fine. It seems TCPDF render the text as HTML

```
$strText = str_replace("\n","<br>",$strText);
$pdf->MultiCell($width, $height,$strText, 0, 'J', 0, 1, '', '', true, null, true);
```

Comment: Can you update your code with what parameters you are passing ? for instance $w =205, $h = 10. It may be easy to understand for expert users, I am not. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

After having so many nightmares, I found a solution.

```
utf8_decode(chr(10))
```

I tried `\n`, `<br/>` and `chr(10)` but nothing worked. Then I realized that it was `utf-8` and just tried the above one. It works fine with `MultiCell` but not with `Cell`.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I've found was:

```
$text = 'Line one\n\nLine two');
$text = explode('\n', $text);

foreach ($text as $txt){
    $pdf->Write($txt);
    $pdf->Ln();
}
```

So this way, you may have any number of \n in any position, if you're getting this text dinamically from the database, it will break lines correctrly.

Answer (score 2):

```
MultiCell($w, $h, 'text<br />', $border=0, $align='L', $fill=1, $ln=0,
    $x='', $y='', $reseth=true, $reseth=0, $ishtml=true, $autopadding=true,
    $maxh=0);
```

You can configure the `MultiCell` to read html on a basic level.

Answer (score 1):

```
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(#);
$pdf->MultiCell($height,$width,"Line1 \nLine2 \nLine3",1,'C',1);
```

In every Column, before you set the X Position indicate first the Y position, so it became like this

Column 1

```
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(#);
$pdf->MultiCell($height,$width,"Line1 \nLine2 \nLine3",1,'C',1);
```

Column 2

```
$pdf->SetY($Y_Fields_Name_position);
$pdf->SetX(#);
$pdf->MultiCell($height,$width,"Line1 \nLine2 \nLine3",1,'C',1);
```

Comment: According to documentation http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm first argument of MultiCell is `width` not `height`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it´s too late but I solved this issue in a very simple way, 
I am using the Multicell option and the text come from a form, if I use an input field to get the text I can´t insert line breaks in any way, but if use a textarea field, the line breaks in the text area are line breaks in the multicell ... and that´s it, it works even if I use `utf8_encode($text)` option to preserve accents

Answer (score 0):

Or just try this after each text passage for a new line.

`$pdf->Write(0, '   ', '*', 0, 'C', TRUE, 0, false, false, 0) ;`

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions (works with TCPDF)

Use HEREDOC for a long string. Put HERDOC for a CONST for example (define different languages)

```
$_prepare_const_EN = <<<EOT
this is a long string
and new line as well ...
EOT;

$define('STR_EN', $_prepare_const_EN);

$pdf->InsertText(STR_EN);
```

works for me wery well....

Answer (score -2):

```
pars_text.append(content[0])
pdf.multi_cell(w=190, txt = content[0])
pdf.ln();  # this
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32529500)