# Sending response as pdf from Servlet

Tags: servlets

I am reading a file content and sending it to browser as content type "PDF",Data in the PDf not identifying line breaks.

I am using, Itext jar and formatting HTML using HTMLWorker.

Could any one help or any source code?

My Code so Far:

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
    document.open();
    String cnt = SAMPLEJAVA.getFileContent("D:/abc.docx");
    System.out.println(cnt);
    HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    String str = "<html><body><pre>" + cnt + "</pre></body></html>";
    htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
    document.close();
    System.out.println("Done");
} catch(Exception ex)  {
}
```

Comment: please provide code snippet that you have wrote for this functionality.

Comment: Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
  response.setContentType("application/pdf");
  try {
   PdfWriter.getInstance(document, response.getOutputStream());
   document.open();
   String cnt=SAMPLEJAVA.getFileContent("D:/abc.docx");
   System.out.println(cnt);
   HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
   String str = "<html><body><pre>"+cnt+"</pre></body></html>";
   htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader(str));
   document.close();
   System.out.println("Done");
   }
   catch{
   
   }

Comment: I think your issue might be with line break char in "D:/abc.docx" file which is "\n" is not getting interpreted in PDF.  You can take the content and try replacing newline char to some PDF understandable newline char and then send as response. this link might help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861809/inserting-line-breaks-into-pdf

Comment: Hi Jayesh, that is not an issue, System.out.println(cnt) is giving me content perfectly and also,when I copy "str" in another html file it is fine,problem would be  HTMLWorker

Comment: I am not sure but I think you have to check what is the newline char understood by PDF. It will work perfectly in other scenario because place where you are trying there it understands "\n" as newline char.

Comment: HTMLWorker is now deprecated (http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/html/simpleparser/HTMLWorker.html). I think you should go with the XML Worker (http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/flatsite.html).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing this line of code:

```
String str = "<html><body><pre>" + cnt + "</pre></body></html>";
```

with this:

```
String str = "<html><body><pre>" + cnt.replace("\n", "&#xD;") + "</pre></body></html>";
```

Comment: is newline char in PDF is "&#xD;" ?

Comment: @Madham if an answer helps you you can upvote it and accept it

Comment: upvote?..How can v add header and footer to pdf like a logo to header

Comment: upvote is that triangle on the left of the answer. and the accept is the tick sign below the triangle :p

Comment: about the header you can create a different question and write me a comment so that i have a look at it. right now its difficult cause i am on mobile