# Adding linebreak on fpdf cells

Tags: php, loops, fpdf

I must add a linebreak for my images to appear after each other. I have tried the following but it does not work.

```
$rs['imagepath'] = $imagepath;
    $pdf->Image("{$imagepath}\n");
```

The original code to output the images is below, but it outputs only the first index and the second and third images does not come up... :(

```
$rs['imagepath'] = $imagepath;
    $pdf->Image("{$imagepath}");
```

The result is in a foreach loop like this:

```
     foreach($select as $index => $rs) 
{    
        $rs['imagepath'] = $imagepath;
        $pdf->Image("{$imagepath}"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use ln() function i think.you have to define every image in one line**

```
$fpdf->ln();
```

Comment: I can not define evey image seperately, The images must loop by themselves if there are more than one images. And thats why I want a linebreak. Can you give an example?

Comment: have a look on this link 1.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861809/inserting-line-breaks-into-pdf       2.http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto1.htm

Comment: Here is my only input: '$rs['imagepath'];. And I want to add a linebreak after this input. And the loop will do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has a mistake, try the below code to iterate over the `$rs` array. in the current code, your `$imagepath` variable is always remain same. you can then print a `\n` characters to pdf for printing new lines

```
foreach($select as $index => $rs) 
{    
        $imagepath = $rs['imagepath'];
        $pdf->Image("{$imagepath}"); 
}
```

**Edit:** **I found this on another stack overflow thread**

If you are using fpdf, in order to be able to use line breaks you will need to use a multi-line text cell as described [here.](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/multicell.htm)

If you use this, then line breaks in your text should be interpreted and converted correctly.

Just a quick example:

```
$pdf->Multicell(0,2,"This is a multi-line text string\nNew line\nNew line");
```

Here, 2 is the height of the multi-line text box. I don't know what units that's measured in or if you can just set it to 0 and ignore it. Perhaps try it with a large number if at first, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use the '/n' for linebreak for a loop?

Comment: I dont know what to add into new lines. It is an automatic loop and I only got one input which will loop all of the results. Here is my only input: '$rs['imagepath'];'. And I also don't know how to output an image into a multicell. In this case only file name is going to be outputted. I want the image itself to me outputted.

Comment: Then what I suggest you is to refer some more places and learn some more. and I don't understand what you mean by an automatic loop :(). the multicell i suggested was to output a new line, to print an image to pdf you can check this http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm