# Adding line break (php) does not work as initially expected

Tags: php, html, line-breaks

I've been trying the following code to add a break line when a product title has more than 60 characters:

```
    if ($item->getProductType() == 'bundle') {
        foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
            $childProduct = $this->productRepositoryInterface->getById(
                $child->getProductId(),
                false,
                $quote->getStoreId()
            );
            $childName = $childProduct->getName();
            $bundleText[] = $childName;
        }
        $line[] = [
            'text' => wordwrap($childName,60,"<br>\n"),
            'feed' => $feed + 10,
            'isProductLine' => true,
            'addToTop' => 5,
            'font' => 'regular',
            'font_size' => $fontSize
        ];
    }

    $optionLineCount = 0;
    if (isset($optionText)) {
        $optionLineCount += count($optionText);
    }

    if (isset($bundleText)) {
        $optionLineCount += count($bundleText);
    }
```

The result of this is (unwanted result):

```
RSM-408A: 8-Port Real-time Redundant Ring Switch with metal<br> case (+12 ~ +48 VDC, non-isolation)
```

Instead of (the desired result):

```
RSM-408A: 8-Port Real-time Redundant Ring Switch with metal
case (+12 ~ +48 VDC, non-isolation)
```

Any ideas of what i'm still missing?

Comment: where did you view your output is?

Comment: @slier the output is generated in a pdf document (Magento 2.3.3; custom module that extends the Cart2Quote PDF module)

Comment: `<br>` does not work in pdf's. I'm quite sure you need to use `"\n"`

Comment: @Jullian obviously Pdf dont understand what is `<br>` tag is, Maybe you looking for `\r`

Comment: you can try `\r\n` if not then `\r` or `\n` if still not working.. just remove the `<br>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861809/inserting-line-breaks-into-pdf

Comment: @all "\n" , "\r" , "\r\n" or removing the <br> still does not render the desired result

Comment: Ok. Try `PHP_EOL` as a constant. not inside " "

Comment: @all Unfortunately PHP_EOL is not working either; any other ideas?